# Input pipeline based on tfrecord, the queue are always empty

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem with tensorflow and a tfrecord based input pipeline.

Each of my records contains:

- 'image' a 3 dimensional array of dimension [480,585,5] with datatype uint8
- 'target' a 4 dimensional array of dimension [7,7,1,6] with datatype float32

This is the code sample that I use to read the data from the tfrecord and create a minibatch:

```
def getBatch(filenames,num_examples):

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames,num_epochs=None)

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    batch_of_example = tf.train.batch([serialized_example],num_examples, capacity=2500, num_threads=16)
    features = tf.parse_example(
        batch_of_example,
        features={
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([7,7,1,6], tf.float32),
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
    )

    image_raw = tf.reshape(tf.decode_raw(features['image'],tf.uint8),[num_examples,480,585,5])
    #rescale images for neural network
    images =tf.image.resize_images(image_raw,[224,224])

    return images,feature['label']
```

However when I try to use it in a training routine the performance are really bad (6/7 example for second with a relatively small net on a Titan X) and neither the cpu nor the gpu seems to be under high work load.

I am using as training set 26 tfrecord file with 2500 example each (~3.5GB each) and a batch size of 32.

I think that the slow performance are caused by the input queue always empty as can be seen from 
[this graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afWAB.png)

Can anybody spot where the problem in my input pipeline is? Or can anybody give me some guidance on why I have such bad performance?